# A question about normal extensions in saturated models

Tags: model-theory

I'm reading the paper ["Weak forms of elimination of imaginaries"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220083027_Weak_forms_of_elimination_of_imaginaries) by Casanovas and Farré, where it is considered the notion of normal extension for small subsets of a big saturated model $M$:

**Definition**: If $A\subseteq B\subseteq M$, then $B$ is normal over $A$, or, equivalently, $B/A$ is **normal**, if one of the following equivalent conditions holds:

1. $\forall f \in\mathrm{Aut}(M/A)$, $f(B)=B$;
2. $\mathrm{Gal}(B/A)=${$f\restriction_B\,:f\in\mathrm{Aut}(M/A)$}.

Where, $\mathrm{Aut}(M/A)$ denotes the groups of all automorphisms of $M$ which fix $A$ pointwise, and $\mathrm{Gal}(B/A)$ denotes the group of all elementary permutations of $B$ which fix $A$ pointwise, respectively.

It is then observed that if $B$ is normal over $A$, then $B\subseteq\mathrm{acl}(A)$ and $\mathrm{dcl}(B)/A$ is also normal. Clearly, $B/A$ normal means that any automorphism that fixes $A$ pointwise can only permute the elements of $B$, but it is not clear to me why every element of $B$ should have a finite orbit over $A$ since $B$ could be infinite.

Is there some detail I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $B$ could be infinite, but can't be large, by hypothesis. If there is some $b\in B$ such that $p(y)=\mathrm{tp}(b/A)$ is non-algebraic, then by saturation of $M$, $p$ has a large number of realizations in $M$. By homogeneity of $M$, the set of realizations of $p$ is the orbit of $b$ under $\mathrm{Aut}(M/A)$, so if $B$ is a normal extension of $A$, then this set is contained in $B$, and hence $B$ is large.

---

In the comments, you asked for clarification on why a non-algebraic type $p$ must have a large number of realizations in $M$. The basic idea is that using the saturation of $M$, we can "keep realizing $p$" until we have a large number of realizations. This idea leads naturally to a proof by transfinite induction, which works just fine. But here's a slightly more elegant "one-step" approach.

First, recall that there is a cardinal $\kappa$ such that the big model $M$ is $\kappa$-saturated and $\kappa$-strongly homogeneous. (If you assume the big model is fully saturated, then $\kappa = |M|$ and strong homogeneity follows from saturation.) Then "small" means cardinality $<\kappa$ and "large" means cardinality $\geq \kappa$.

Suppose $p(x)$ is a non-algebraic type over the small set $A$. I claim that $p(x)$ has a large number of realizations in $M$.

Since $p(x)$ is non-algebraic, there is *some* model $N$ containing $A$ such that $p(x)$ has infinitely many realizations in $N$. By Löwenheim-Skolem, and since $A$ is small, we can assume that $N$ is small, and thus embeds elementarily in $M$ over $A$. It follows that $p(x)$ has infinitely many realizations in $M$.

Now let $C = p(M) = \{c\in M\mid M\models p(c)\}$. Assume for contradiction that $C$ is small, and consider the type $p(x)\cup \{x\neq c\mid c\in C\}$. This is a type over the small set of parameters $A\cup C$, which is consistent by compactness: Since $p(M)$ is infinite, we can always find a realization of $p$ in $M$ which is distinct from any finitely many elements of $C$. But by definition of $C$, this type has no realizations in $M$, contradicting saturation.

Comment: Thank you @Alex for your answer. It is not clear to me why if $p(y)$ is not algebraic, then it must necessarily have a large number of realizations in $M$. Why an infinite small amount of realizations is not possible?

Comment: @F.Salviati  I've edited my answer to explain that point.

Comment: Ok perfect, I've never noticed that property of types in a saturated model. Now I see it: many thanks, @Alex.

Comment: @F.Salviati Glad I could help. If my answer resolves your question, you can upvote and accept it (the up arrow and green check mark to the left of the answer). Welcome to Math Stackexchange!